# How do restructure the trip data to prepare a link data using spread and gather functions in R?

Tags: r, tidyr, spread

I have a trip data set as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(user =c("P001", "P001", "P002"), tripID = c("tid1", "tid2", "tid3"), mode =c("bus", "train", "taxi"), Origin = c("Westmead", "Redfan", "Westmead"), Destination = c("Redfan", "Darlington", "Strathfield"), depart_dt = c("8:00", "8:30", "8:45") )
```

I need to restructure the above data using probably spread() and gather() functions from tidyr to prepare a link trip data as follows:

```
df_new <- data.frame(user=c("P001", "P002"), tripID = c("newtid1", "newtid2"), mode = c("bus + train", "taxi"), Origin = c("Westmead", "Westmead" ), Destination = c("Darlington", "Strathfield"), depart_dt = c("8:00", "8:45"))
```

I am a new bee in R. Can anyone help me here?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @Nirbhay Singh for your advice to improve the query statement.

Comment: Glad to help. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(user =c("P001", "P001", "P002"), tripID = c("tid1", "tid2", "tid3"), mode =c("bus", "train", "taxi"), Origin = c("Westmead", "Redfan", "Westmead"), Destination = c("Redfan", "Darlington", "Strathfield"), depart_dt = c("8:00", "8:30", "8:45") )

df %>%
  group_by(user) %>%
  arrange(depart_dt, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  summarize(Origin = Origin[1], mode = paste(mode, collapse = " + "),
            Destination = Destination[length(Destination)],
            depart_dt = depart_dt[1]) %>%
  mutate(tripID = paste0("newtid", row_number()))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   user  Origin   mode        Destination depart_dt tripID 
#>   <fct> <fct>    <chr>       <fct>       <fct>     <chr>  
#> 1 P001  Westmead bus + train Darlington  8:00      newtid1
#> 2 P002  Westmead taxi        Strathfield 8:45      newtid2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `spread()` or `gather()` (or their successors `pivot_longer.` and `pivot_wider()`.
The below should give you what you want.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(user) %>% 
  arrange(tripID, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(mode = str_c(mode, collapse = " + "),
            Origin = first(Origin),
            Destination = last(Destination),
            depart_dt = first(depart_dt)) %>% 
  mutate(tripID = str_c("newtrid", row_number()))

#   user  mode        Origin   Destination depart_dt tripID  
#   <fct> <chr>       <fct>    <fct>       <fct>     <chr>   
# 1 P001  bus + train Westmead Darlington  8:00      newtrid1
# 2 P002  taxi        Westmead Strathfield 8:45      newtrid2
```

Comment: Nice answer, +1. I like the use of `first` and `last`, definitely looks cleaner than indexing.

Comment: I agree with you. But can I use spread() and gather() functions here to get this same answer from this given data ?

Comment: But if we have more than 1000 trips for 100 users from different origins to different destinations in different time during 5 months period, in this case the above solution could not help me to restructure the given trip segment data to construct a full journey data for individual users. Can anyone help this point of view?

Comment: Why does this not help you? Could you explain what goes wrong?